# GATE: JAPE rule Java RHS feature map

Tags: java, nlp, grammar, gate

I am trying to get existing annotations and their features within a Sentence annotation i.e for each sentence, there may be multiple annotations which have a i.e majorType, string and type features.

I want a new ‘Sentence contains’ annotation with a feature map of the contained annotations and their respective features.

I believe it should be an extension of the below rule from the excellent Gate Jape Grammar Tutorial pdf :

```
Phase:usingJAVAinRHS  
Input:  Lookup  
Options: control = all  
Rule: javainRHS1  
(  
{Lookup.majorType == Team}  
)  
:team  
-->  
{  
gate.AnnotationSet team = (gate.AnnotationSet)bindings.get("team");       
gate.Annotation teamAnn = (gate.Annotation)team.iterator().next();   
gate.FeatureMap features = Factory.newFeatureMap(); 
features.put("teamOfSport", teamAnn.getFeatures().get("minorType"));  
features.put("rule","javainRHS1");  
outputAS.add(team.firstNode(), team.lastNode(), "Team",features); }
```

Except in my new rule, I want to annotate the Sentence, then get the contained annotation:

```
Phase:usingJAVAinRHS  
Input:  Lookup Sentence  
Options: control = all  
Rule: javainRHS1  
(  
{Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType == Team}}  
)  
:team  
-->  
{  
gate.AnnotationSet team = (gate.AnnotationSet)bindings.get("team");   
gate.Annotation teamAnn = (gate.Annotation)team.iterator().next();   
gate.FeatureMap features = Factory.newFeatureMap(); 
features.put("teamOfSport",   teamAnn.getFeatures().get("minorType"));  
features.put("rule","javainRHS1");  
outputAS.add(team.firstNode(), team.lastNode(), "Team",features); }
```

How do you get the feature map of the contained annotations?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach to get all annotation contained in a sentence and store in feature map based on their majorType or kind.

```
Imports: {
import static gate.Utils.*;
}
Phase:usingJAVAinRHS  
Input:  Lookup Sentence  
Options: control = appelt
Rule: javainRHS1  
(  
{Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType == Team}}  
)  
:team  
-->  
{  
    gate.AnnotationSet team = (gate.AnnotationSet)bindings.get("team"); 
    gate.FeatureMap features = Factory.newFeatureMap(); 
    for(Annotation annotation:team.inDocumentOrder())  
    {
        if(annotation.getType() == "Lookup"){
            features.put(annotation.getFeatures().get("majorType"),stringFor(doc,annotation));
        }
        else{
            features.put(annotation.getType(), stringFor(doc,annotation));
        }
    }
    features.put("rule","javainRHS1");  
    outputAS.add(team.firstNode(), team.lastNode(), "Team",features); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added your suggestion which works in the sense that it doesn’t throw errors but only spits out the sentence annotation, sentence string and rule name as features. It doesn’t output the majorType of the ‘Team’ annotation. Is there anything further I need to change?

Comment: I can't find you... Can you ping me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new annotation just to find out "Team" and write another rule where you copy the annotation of Team to default Sentence annotation in the RHS

I have a similar jape rule where I need the annotate the sentence and add the numbers in the sentence as its features.

```
Imports: {import gate.Utils;}

Phase:Sentence
Input: Token
Options: control = appelt
Rule: Number
(
    {Token.category ==~ CD}
):num
-->
:num.Number = {Number = :num.Token.string}

Phase:Sentence
Input: Sentence
Options: control = appelt
Rule: GetNumber
({Sentence}):tag
-->
{
  Annotation numSent = Utils.getOnlyAnn(bindings.get("tag"));
  List<Annotation> val = Utils.inDocumentOrder(Utils.getContainedAnnotations(inputAS, numSent, "Number"));
  List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>(val.size());
  for(Annotation a : val) {
    str.add((String)a.getFeatures().get("Number"));
  }
  numSent.getFeatures().put("Number", str);
}
```

This code will Annotate the sentence using default Sentence annotation but display the Number annotation's features inside Sentence annotation's features.

Here is the output image:

[image]